# Recommended way to create aggregate entities

Tags: domain-driven-design

Suppose, I have aggregate name "**ABCD**" which is root entity and another entity "**IJKL**" in that aggregate. My question is , what is the recommended way to create entity of IJKL and persist in database

Comment: You map it using an ORM or use event sourcing to record the state change.

Comment: In my IABCDRepository can i have method like,                    public static void SaveIJKL(IJKL ijklObject)

Comment: In my app service layer can i have service with method like void SaveIJKL(IJKL ijklObject)

Answer (score 0):

By the very definition of an aggregate the lifetime of IJKL is coupled to the lifetime of ABCD, so you shouldn't be creating IJKLs explicitly; instead you should be calling logic on ABCD which will decide (internally) how/when to deal with IJKL(s).

For new instances, the aggregate creation logic should be encapsulated in a factory, and that factory will be responsible for 'newing up' IJKL instances together with the rest of the aggregate.

For persistence concerns (load/save of existing entities) the logic should be part of the repository's SaveABCD method, which is responsible for persistance of the entire aggregate.

If you consistently find yourself with the need to manipulate IJKL(s) directly then there is a problem with your aggregate - either ABCD is not the correct root, or IJKL needs to be in a separate aggregate.

Comment: In my project, I have Advertiser entity which is root entity of aggregate and there is bonusprogram entity in that aggregate, bonusprogram entity(bonusprogram is like commitment, for eg -: if Advertiser subscribe to bonusprogram A, that means  advertiser has to make 20 new ads with in one month which results in $100 bonus, advertiser will get) is not created by Advertiser, but advertiser can subscribe only to bonsuprogram from the dropdown list. Now if admin want to add new bonusprogram in the current bonusprogram list, how will he do that  ? Remember he cannot do that with Advertiser .